# Azure Notification Hub for iOS on Ad Hoc not working

Tags: ios, azure, notifications

I have a notification hub set up. I have 2 endpoints, one for dev and one for production. I am using iOS.

I had both the ad hoc and dev working and then not. It is like it is hit and miss.

Currently the Dev will work and gets messages just fine.

When I build for Ad Hoc, however, the messages never get back to the device.

I am using a real device.

The hub monitor shows successful registration. It also shows incoming messages and successful notifications.

And yet on the device I never hit the method that is the incoming message.

I have added NSLogs and looked at the console output running the Ad Hoc since you can't debug Ad Hoc. I see the response from registration as successful. I just never see the message notification.

What do I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that if you ever use the debug credentials to log into the production hub it screws up the production hub and you have to delete and recreate it.

Comment: did anyone confirm this answer? What do you exactly mean by "use the debug credentials to log into the production hub"? My production hug has thousands of users registered to it, and I cannot just delete it :(

Comment: Sorry to hear that you have thousands of users because as far I could can tell the only way to fix it is to delete it.

Comment: Arg, hit enter. Wasn't done with the comment. What I mean by use the debug credentials is if you set the URL of the hub to the production hub, but have the app compiled with the development provisioning profile and connect to that production hub it hoses the hub somehow. I got a response from a Microsoft tech to this effect.